# Which of these Mountain Bikes Choices is the Best?

Tags: mountain-bike, beginner

The choices from local bike stores:

1. Used [2015 Cannondale SL 29 - 2](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=3053292) (Women's) - $750
2. 2019 Haro Doublepeak 27.5 Trail - $760
3. 2018 Specialized Pitch Comp 27.5 (Women's) -$700
4. 2019 Specialized Rockhopper Sport 29 - $710
5. 2019 Trek Roscoe 6 - $800

Also, my local bike stores probably have all other common models of Trek bikes if there is a different one you think would be better. I'm also not opposed to ordering a bike online, if there is a better option.

I don't have much experience mountain biking, I currently have a 2005 Fuji Nevada hybrid bike that I've done some light mountain biking with.

I am a 5'8" male. I don't have any issue with buying a women's bike though.

From these options, I'm currently leaning towards the used Cannondale SL 29, but like I said, I'm not very knowledgeable.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Sorry ben - we consider shopping questions off topic because there's limited long-term use to these kind of answers.   Your best razor is to buy the most comfortable bike to you, and to know that means trying them out in person.   Do have a browse of the [tour] to learn how SE works, as a Q&A format.